# When may one do a Hechi Kedushah?

Tags: tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, kedusha-prayer, heiche-kedusha

May a Chazzan decide on his own to do a [Hechi Kedushah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1662/5), or are there rules for when it is appropriate/mandated?

Comment: Alternatively known as "Hoiche / Heiche Kedushah" or "Chatzi Kedusha." (Actually, I don't think I've ever heard it pronounced "Hechi.")

Comment: @Dave, I'm generally pretty Makpid on spelling/transliterating Hebrew, but since I'm not even entirely sure what language it is, I spelled it the way it generally sounds to me when I hear it.

Comment: @SethJ - no prob, I just wanted to clarify for those who might not understand the title.

Comment: @SethJ - Also known as *Heicha Kedushah*?

Comment: @AdamMosheh, I think your above 2 points were already addressed earlier.

Comment: Side note: The Previous Lubavitcher Rebbe said about a personal Hechi Kedushah that its bad enough you came to shul late, but now you want to announce it to the entire congregation?

Comment: @user1292 That's a good reason for the latecomer to avoid coming late again, NOT to ignore part of Halacha.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch ([OC 232:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=286)) recommends doing this when השעה דחוקה=the time is pressing, which the Rama ([OC 124:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=288)) defines as when the congregation is afraid that if they do the full repetition they won't finish by the end of the allotted time for that prayer. (See Biur Halacha [OC 124](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=288) sv SheYa'avor who debates if this is Chatzot or Sof Zman Tefillah in regards to Shacharit.)

The Mishna Berurah there ([sk 6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=288)) points out that if it is not a pressing time one should not do this, as the proper form of the enactment of Chazal is to have the repetition come *after* the silent prayer.

---

The Aruch HaShulchan ([OC 232:7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%91#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A8.D7.9C_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.96)) suggests that, at a very small minyan where it is doubtful that 9 people will answer Amen (as they tend to talk, etc.), one should always do a Heichi Kedusha lest the leader's blessings during his repetition be levatala.

Comment: Although it's odd, I've actually seen a Shul do it for Musaf on Shabbath. I'm pretty sure they weren't pressed for time bc of Zeman, but they might have (legitimately) felt pressure to finish by a certain time for logistical and Tzorech HaTzibur issues. Does anyone state that the ShU"'A might allow for other pressing situations?

Comment: @SethJ - I once heard of a (Conservative?) Shul that does this for both Shacharith and Musaf on Shabbath.

Comment: @AdamMosheh, Interesting. Any idea where?

Comment: Our Conservative shul in Gaithersburg, Maryland, does a Heiche Kedushah for mussaf on Shabbat. We have a lot of families with young children and our Rabbi feels pressure to finish the main service in sync with the children's services, so that families are reunited before the kids "have a melt-down." We have experimented with a break-away minyan for Mussaf (both to have a full Amidah and to experiment with alternative niggunim) but it didn't seem to attract the attendance it needed.

Comment: It is my experience that many Conservative synagogues do a heicha kedusha for musaf.  I have also been in a Chabad that did this for the same sorts of reasons (the tzibbur will not tolerate more davening/won't pay attention anyway).

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen Probably better to cut out half of Pesukei Dizimra, all the Yekum Purkan stuff, and Anim Zemirot than to skip the repetition.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Maybe those are things they should have done.  I am merely eporting what they actually did.

Answer (score 10):

I read in *The Making of a Gadol* that (according to R' Yaakov Kaminetzky) in Kenesses Yisroel in Slabodka during the week they did a hoiche kedusha for mincha because the institution of chazaras hashatz was for a beis hakenneses where baal habatim davened because of the possible presence of the ignorant, not for a beis medrash of baalei torah.  Friday mincha, though, they did a full chazaras hashatz because many baalei batim came for shabbos davening. (I guess that made it into a shul?)

Comment: Wow, I really don't like the logic there, but thanks for the interesting anecdote! I'm not sure it answers the question, but since I'm not sure it doesn't, and since it's really interesting, +1 from me.

Comment: I have heard that this logic is what a number of _y'shivos_ rely on.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16958/why-do-we-still-do-chazarat-hashatz

Comment: @msh210, I'm not actually criticizing the logic per se (I know, it sounded like I was); I'm <strike>criticizing</strike> <strike>questioning</strike> inquiring about the assumption that the logic is based upon, that Ḥazarath HaSha"Tz is _only_ for the ignorant and is superfluous in a B"M or Yeshivah.

Comment: @YDK - Which page in the book is it on?

Comment: I do not know.  I have since returned the book to its owner in Eretz Yisrael.

Comment: I've tried unsuccessfully to find earlier sources that make this point. Isn't it odd that such an important built-in heter to a common takana isn't mentioned prominently until the last century?

Comment: @YDK So all of the chachamim that davened with a normal chazaras ha'shatz before them were baalei batim? If such a reason developed so late, seems a little funny...

Comment: @sethJ, I also thought part of the Chazarat HaShatz was to end up with 100 berachot each day per Dovid haMelech.