# Doing "Hoiche Kedushah" for Shacharit

Tags: halacha, tefilla, time, shacharis-morning-prayer, hacham-ovadia-yosef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hechi Kedushah anytime?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16998/hechi-kedushah-anytime)

Do any posekim say that even in shacharit, one can do the "hoiche kedushah" if the minyan-goers really need to go to work, or are in a rush for some other reason.  I remember reading that Rav Ovadia Yosef writes this.  Where does he write this?

Comment: What makes you think that 'really need to go to work' is a reason to do Heichi Kedusha?

Comment: What makes you think Shacharit is different from Mincha?

Comment: Harav Ovadia holds it's very Dohak.

Comment: There is an issue of Semicha Geula L'Tefila which can be problem unless the Hoiche Kedusha is done with the Minyan saying it along quietly.