# Minimum number of people to start the Chazara

Tags: minyan

In a minian, what is the minimum number of people that are able to answer required to start the chazara with the chazan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן כ - דין חזרת תפלת השליח צבור](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0019_L2) says you need **at least 9 people answering Amen**.

> **סעיף ב':** 
>   בַּחֲזָרַת תְפִלַּת הַשְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר, כֵּיוָן שֶׁהַשְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר כְּבָר הִתְפַּלֵּל בִּפְנֵי עַצְמוֹ בְּלַחַשׁ, וְאֵינוֹ חוֹזֵר אֵת הַתְּפִלָּה רַק בִּשְׁבִיל הַשּׁוֹמְעִים, לָכֵן **צְרִיכִין שֶׁיִּהְיוּ דַּוְקָא תִּשְׁעָה שׁוֹמְעִין וְעוֹנִין, שֶׁלֹּא תִּהְיֶינָה בִּרְכוֹתָיו לְבַטָּלָה** (וְלָא דָמֵי לְמַה שֶׁכָּתוּב בְּסִימָן ט"ו סָעִיף ז'). וְלָכֵן כְּשֶׁיֵּשׁ מִנְיָן מְצֻמְצָם, צְרִיכִין לְהַשְׁגִיחַ שֶׁלֹּא יַתְחִיל הַשְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר חֲזָרַת הַתְּפִלָּה עַד שֶׁיִּגְמְרוּ כֻלָּן תְּפִלּוֹתֵיהֶן שֶׁיּוּכְלוּ לַעֲנוֹת‏

Comment: related AHS http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17003/759