Guide to managing critically small minyan
I would like to study halachot that will lead me to have a better grasp of how to deal with the ins and outs of a very small minyan, such as 10 or 11 people. There are so many questions I will just give 3 as an example:

what if in the middle of chazara/kaddish, someone goes to the toilet and we only have 9 saying amen?
what leniences can be relied on regarding zman, e.g. if number 10 is late for mincha and it is nearly sunset, at what point should the minyan give up and daven without/go find another minyan?
if minyan gets up to birchat kriyat shema for shacharit when there is only 9, and number 10 turns up then, should he be advised to skip things or can he continue at his own pace.

As you can see, there are a lot of ins and outs. Are there any comprehensive guides, or a list of good simanim in Shulchan Aruch etc to help people who are trying to manage with a very small minyan?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17003/759

See siman 55 in orach chaim
