# Is there tefillah betzibbur during mixed heiche kedusha?

Tags: halacha, minhag, tefilla, minyan, heiche-kedusha

In a *minyan* (quorum) that is doing [*heiche kedushe*](http://www.jewish-languages.org/jewish-english-lexicon/words/1546) with the (inevitable?) scenario that some *mispallelim* (ones praying) are following the [*Rama*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Isserles) and waiting till after the [*chazzan*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazzan)'s [*kedusha*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kedushah) to begin their silent [*amidah*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amidah) while some are following the [Sefardi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sephardi_Jews)/[Brisker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brisk_tradition_and_Soloveitchik_dynasty) minhag (custom) to *daven* (pray) the first 3 *brachot* (blessings) together with the chazzan, and assuming that there are not 10 of each group present, is anyone *yotzei* (fulfilling) *tefillah betzibbur* (praying with a quorum)?

Comment: (It probably makes more sense to ask this after the [other question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59619/759) is answered and you have any sense of if tefillah betzibbur is even a factor here.) Why do you think it should be? Why would anyone fulfill TbTz if everyone is going liek one opinion but not if it's half and half

Comment: @DoubleAA That question would potentially apply even if there are 10 of each group present.

Comment: You don't ask about that case though. You ask about a very specific case and give no motivation for choosing that case (not to mention not sourcing any of your claims about how various groups practice). Overall a pretty poor post.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer. Reb Shlomo Zalman Auerbach is quoted in Halichos Shlomo on tefila chapter 9 siff 2 as saying "a person praying along with the Shliach Tzibur is counted as part of the ten for the minyan, and even when there are not nine men answering without counting him, the Shliach Tzibur may say the chazaras hashatz."

Footnote #2 explains his logic. "Since this person is praying along with the Shatz word for word, he is no worse than a Shomea K'Onah, and it is as if there are nine people answering.

However this is only true when most of the minyan have already finished their tefila, but if most have not yet finished, lichatchila the Shatz should not start, even though there are ten people answering"

From here at least we can see regarding your situation, if less than the majority of people are saying along with the Shatz, it would be fine. More than that would need a different approach.