# Chazan's Recitation of Shmona Esrei - Nusach Ashkenaz

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, nusach-ashkenaz, kedusha-prayer, chazarat-hashatz

In nusach Ashkenaz, the chazzan's repetition of Shmona Esrei skips the paragraph beginning with "אתה קדוש ושמך קדוש", and connects the qedusha with the following brakha ("אתה חונן לאדם דעת") by means of a paragraph that commences, "לדור ודור נגיד גדלך".

I am given to understand (but have no source) that if the congregation is pressed for time, the chazzan can skip the repetition by starting the Shmona Esrei out loud, continuing until qedusha, reciting qedusha and then letting everybody daven the rest of Shmona Esrei silently, to themselves. In the event that this happens, should he say "לדור ודור", or let them all say "אתה קדוש"?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1662/how-does-one-do-hechi-kedusha

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16998/759

Comment: Can you clarify what the congregation is saying when?

Comment: Check this: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%93_%D7%91 (If this answers your question, let me know, and I'll write an answer.)

Answer (score 4):

When I asked my LOR the rules in these situations he said:

- The Chazzan starts the Shemoneh Esrei out loud as you mentioned.
- He says the Kedusha with the Congregation as usual, and he finishes לדור ודור
- At that point he continues silently by himself (and does not say אתה קדוש)
- At the end of Kedusha the Congregation takes three steps back and three steps forward and starts the entire Shemoneh Esrei from the beginning silently, and would therefore say אתה קדוש at the appropriate place.

So both would be said, לדור ודור during the Kedushah, and אתה קדוש during the Congregation's silent Shemoneh Esrei.

Modim DeRabbanan would never be said by anyone.

Comment: This is not uniformly practiced.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.beerot.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%A2/%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9F/tabid/85/ID/45/PageID/55/-2504.aspx), since there's no need to say "אתה קדוש" after already saying *kedushah*, it makes sense to say "לדור ודור" in your mentioned case as well.

And here's a [more lengthy discussion](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50015&st=&pgnum=31&hilite=) on this topic.

Comment: You should give a better summary in English for those who cannot follow the link.

Comment: @sabbahillel . . . especially since it is now a broken link.